# Method implemented from delegate not triggered

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a **UIViewController** which is embedded in a navigation controller and presented modally:

```
//UIViewController
AuthenticationController *auth = [[AuthenticationController alloc] init];

//UINavigationController
AuthRootController *navController = [[AuthRootController alloc]
                                         initWithRootViewController:auth];

navController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Anmelden";
navController.delegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
RELEASE_SAFELY(navController);
```

However there is something wrong with the delegate I created within the AuthRootController class:

```
@protocol AuthRootControllerDelegate

@required
-(void)authRootControllerDidEnd:(UINavigationController *)sender;

@end

@interface AuthRootController : UINavigationController {
    id<AuthRootControllerDelegate>  delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id delegate;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
@implementation AuthRootController
@synthesize delegate;

-(void)userDidCancelController:(UINavigationController *)sender{
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(AuthRootControllerDelegate)]) {
        [self.delegate authRootControllerDidEnd:sender];
    }
}

@end
```

When I use the method

```
-(void)authRootControllerDidEnd:(UINavigationController *)sender
```

it is not triggered. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared that your delegate conforms to AuthRootControllerDelegate? The conformsToProtocol test looks at whether the delegate declares conformance, it doesn't do any sort of method-by-method check. So even if you've implemented authRootControllerDidEnd: on your delegate, conformsToProtocol can still return NO.

Answer (score 0):

In your interface you aren't declaring it as implementing the delegate protocol, you need to modify your interface declaration like this:

```
@interface AuthRootController : UINavigationController<AuthRootControllerDelegate> {
```